# ALT+Tab: How to switch to Desktop on Ubuntu GNOME 17.04?

Tags: gnome, 17.04, .desktop, application-switcher, workspace-switcher

The question might seem like a really stupid one, but I cannot find an answer anywhere. In short, **how to switch to Desktop on Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 Zesty Zapus**?

As we know, Desktop isn't even enabled by default on Ubuntu GNOME, but it has to be activated separately through `Gnome Tweak Tool`. Once the desktop is activated, how is one able to switch to it? In Unity desktop, this happens simply by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and scrolling on top of the purple desktop icon, as demonstrated here:

[image: application switcher]

It's just that, what's the point of enabling the desktop if one cannot fully utilize its existence? Maybe I am missing something here...? :O

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>. Super is normally the windows key - the same which opens the acitivites overview.

To view shortcuts, open settings and go to Keyboard and then the Shortcuts tab. This shortcut is "Hide all normal windows" under Navigation.

[image]

---

Incedentally, <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> also works for me - I'm not sure why!

My pronouns are He / Him

Comment: Haha, someone has even taken time to make an extension for those who prefer something visual ;-) https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/64/show-desktop-button/